# java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'apiuser@x.x.x.x in WSO Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am configuring WSO2 Idenity server in AWS Cloud.I am installing WSO2 Identity server in EC2.
I am using an AWS RDS MYSQL database and i have create apiuser in it.Its in different end point than in EC2.
Also i changed master-datasources.xml to point to the RDS Server like below using the end point of RDS  than localhost.

jdbc:mysql://myrdsendpoint:3306/apimgt?autoReconnect=true&relaxAutoCommit=true&
            apiuser
            apimanager

I have changed at all places where apiuser is referred..
Still i am getting error like  java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'apiuser'@'ec2ip' (using password: YES)
The apiuser is referred from the ec2ip..

Is there any other place which i should change to use apiuser from the RDS rather than EC2?

Comment: are you sure this user can access RDS from EC2 instance? did you try with a mysql client?

Comment: Yes..I installed MySQL Client in EC2 instance and tried...Actually i created this user from EC2 using mySQL client..

And the access denied is shown for apiuser@ec2-ip... Why would that happen?

Comment: are you saying that this user can't login even through the mysql client?

Comment: User can login..no problem there.. But issue happens when identity server is stared

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating user who can be accessed from any machine..

```
CREATE USER apiuser@'%' IDENTIFIED BY ' apimanager';
```

Its solved now..

Comment: Wasn't the IS on the same machine on which you run the mysql client?

Comment: Yes..But i created the user explictly to be accessed only from RDS instance...That step was wrong